# TYPO3 add tables value

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

does somebody know if a user can select on TYPO3 7.6.6 page, multiple values, like price of anything and sum it automatically? Or still exists an extension for those requirements?

I am thankfull for any hint.

Thanks in advance

ayhan

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking - can you elaborate please?

Comment: totally unclear :D

Comment: Okay i try to explain another way. On TYPO3 is possibility to create tables with certain numbers of columns and rows. Is there a posibility to create the tables on a way to make it possible for frontend user to select a number of rows and save this selected rows with all content in a new table? Hope this was clear.